# Alternative to raw_input on arcgis

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool

In python only, I use
S = float(raw_input( 'Insert the value: ')
when I want allow to user insert a value then is used in that script.

When I try to use the same on a python script that I've already implement as script tool on arcgis, it seems no possible because give me an error like this:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 769, in  EOFError: EOF when reading a line

So I infer that the problem is arcpy don't recognize the function "raw_input" or python window doesn't allow that user insert a value..

Can anyone help me to replace python's function raw_input ?

Comment: With your edit, I think this has now become a duplicate of your earlier question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/190534/115 which already has an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Help page entitled [Understanding script tool parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/understanding-script-tool-parameters.htm) that explains how to do this.

You configure the Parameters on the tool dialog and then get them within your script using either `arcpy.GetParameter()` or `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()`.

Comment: I believe it was not what I was asking , I have created the script tool , my question is to create a code with an identical part of the " raw_input ", used in python, that ask the user to enter a value, because when I use raw_input program gives an error

Comment: It seemed to me that you were asking how to ["build custom script tools with input parameters (via arcpy.GetParameterAsText());"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/190541/115).

Comment: I think that 's not what I need.. I just need to request user that insert a value as I can do with python using raw_input and I can't do with arcpy.. Do you understand? @PolyGeo

Comment: Perhaps try editing your question because that seems to be saying something different to your comments. It is your question that gets answered.